# How to convert MATLAB Structure as an MNE Python RAW object

Tags: python, matlab

I have a MATLAB structure (.mat) which I wish to save as a mne raw file.I tried loading the structure into python using the pymatreader and want to now view/ save the contents of the structure as an MNE raw file. Is that possible? Could anyone help me with how to convert the desired data as into a Raw object using which can later be saved, lets say in fif format? An example would be of great help

This is what I have done so far:

```
from pymatreader import read_mat

data = read_mat('newstruct.mat')
```

I found somewhere this:
raw=mne.io.RawArray(dat, info)

How do I exactly find the np array that I need to load in ‘dat’ and is there any way I can get all channel information and names and load it into ‘info’?

This is my file:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1CgX50jMn-cDlp6pp1Jlriop-GYYrc14J/view?usp=sharing